# Offline support on Graphql

Tags: angular, mobile, graphql, offline, ariadne-graphql

All our services are running on python with ariadne and graphql but we have a new challenge. We need to run the application (angular web-application) in offline mode too. The application runs over mobile system. Is there any solution to run the services in offline mode? Using any lib from front-end...

Run service on Offline mode. When the application is running on Online mode the resolvers are resolving all queries and mutations. The challenge is to retrieve the data on Offline mode

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you trying to ask if it's possible to run all your services offline but still communicate with them via the Angular web app?

Comment: Yes, I need build an Apollo federation in front-end part in order to run the application in offline mode. I don't know if it is posible but it is a big challenge.

Comment: This is not feasible. If your entire application's design pattern is that of a true microservice, you have followed the guidelines of federating your graph and the frontend communicates with the backend via then gateway then what you want to archive is not doable. Take time to re-evaluate your applications' system design architecture. You seem to have picked the wrong solution for the right problem.